# process.env.VAR alternative in Go

Tags: go

How to access the environment variable supplied to a single program in Go?

In NodeJS, I was using:

```js
const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT
```

```sh
$ HTTP_PORT=5000 node index.js
```

I am wondering how to get this done in Golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.Getenv()`.

```golang
func main() {
    httpPort := os.Getenv("HTTP_PORT")
    fmt.Printf("HTTP_PORT=%s\n", httpPort)
}
```

While executing:

```sh
$ HTTP_PORT=5000 go run test.go
HTTP_PORT=5000
```

Comment: You can go through https://gobyexample.com if not already done. It's a good starting point; and then [go docs](https://golang.org/doc/)..